# equals and compare with BigDecimal

Tags: java

I have a class overriding `hashCode(`) and `equals()`-method. As I deal with `BigDecimal`, I have to use `compareTo()` instead of `Objects.equals()`:

```
public class MyProduct extends Product{

private BigDecimal price;


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(price);
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) return true; // is this right or should this be deleted

        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        final Product other = (Product) obj;

        // is this right?
        if (price == null ? (other.price != null) : price.compareTo(other.price) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Should I delete the line `if (this == obj) return true;` from `equals()`-method? Because with this line, the compareTo is not triggered and a wrong equals() could be computed, am I right?
2. Could the equals()-method be improved?

Comment: Unless there are cases where you want an object to be unequal to itself, the `if (this==obj)` check is correct.

Comment: I have seen examples where this line is missed when comparing BigDecimal within equals()-method. I cannot find a reason why these examples did not use `if (this==obj)`..

Comment: (#1) How could a wrong equals() be computed if they are the *same* object instance? An object is always equal to itself.

Comment: (#2) *"Could the equals()-method be improved?"* Yeah, you could fix the NullPointerException that happens when `price != null` and `other.price == null`

Comment: @Andreas Ok, that makes sense, so I guess, the other examples I seen were not fully correct..I cannot find an example where I should remove `if (this==obj)` from the `equals()`-method. Do you find any examples?

Comment: "reason"to not use `if (this == obj)` - it is just an optimization, maybe not used to keep example simple?! (it is not wrong not to use it)

Comment: *"Could the equals()-method be improved?"* Depends. Can `MyProduct` be subclassed, and should subclass be able to call `super.equals()`, i.e. the `equals()` of `MyProduct`? If no to first, then make `MyProduct` class `final`. If no to second, then you're good, but otherwise you need to replace `obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()` with `! (obj instanceof MyProduct)`.

Comment: @Andreas yes, right. If you make an answer to this question with your improved equals()-method I will accept it.

Comment: @Andreas some controversy about using  `instanceof` in `equals`! It can break the `equals`contract: "It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true."

Comment: @Andreas I agree: if you make an answer put of your comments, I'd upvote it too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is just an optimization meant to early return a result if both references point to the same object.

Is `price` nullable? I assume it is, as you're checking for it within your `equals()` implementation. In that case your code won't work in case `other.price` will be `null`. Specifically this code here:

```
price.compareTo(other.price) != 0
```

Will throw a `NullPointerException`.

You can fix it like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) return true; // is this right or should this be deleted

        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        final MyProduct other = (MyProduct) obj;

        // If you prefer, the below two can be replaced with a single condition
        // price != null ^ other.price != null
        // Credits to @Andreas
        if (price == null && other.price != null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (price != null && other.price == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (other.price != null && price.compareTo(other.price) != 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return super.equals(obj);
    }
```

Now, you could probably make it shorter, but personally I find it the most readable this way.

Anyways, unless you really, really care about customising your `equals()` implementation, I would suggest generating one with your IDE and sticking to it. They do a decent job most of the time and you don't have to worry about it being broken (although comparing `BigDecimals` may be tricky for them, given you don't care about the scale but rather just the value).

Comment: You should just combine the two null tests: `if (price != null ^ other.price != null) { return false; }` --- **Exclusive-OR:** If exactly one of them is not null, then return false.

Comment: @Andreas (sorry for the spam ;)) I'll steal that from you!

Comment: If this would be a competition to make it shorter, then I probably would. ;-) On a serious note, from my experience it's better to keep such logic as dumb, as possible - even at a price of a few extra keystrokes. Smart code is good until it's smarter than the reader - and maybe it's just me, but bitwise operators always cause me to raise an eyebrow. :)

It's a nice suggestion though!

Comment: @MateuszHerych `^` is not a bitwise operator. It's a **Boolean Logical Operator**, so says JLS [15.22.2. Boolean Logical Operators &, ^, and |](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2). Sure, it is *also* a bitwise (JLS [15.22.1. Integer Bitwise Operators &, ^, and |](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1)).

Comment: However, the suggested equals()-method could also throws a NPE, because the `this.price` could be null and `if (other.price != null && price.compareTo(other.price) != 0) {
            return false;
        }` would throw a NPE.

Comment: @nimo23 it won't because I check for it earlier. Simple unit test proves it - in case `price` is `null` but `other.price` is not, then it will return `false` in the first null-checking if.

Comment: Sonar says `A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "price" is nullable here.` and indicates the line `if (other.price != null && price.compareTo(other.price) != 0) { return false; }`.

Comment: If I use `if ((this.price == null) ? (other.price != null) : this.price.compareTo(other.price) != 0) return false;` then sonar does not complain about a possible NPE.

Comment: Weird, perhaps converting this to else-if will fix sonar here. `price == null && other.price != null` won't pass the first check. IDE doesn't complain for me, it is when I remove the first check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199545/discussion-between-mateusz-herych-and-nimo23).

Comment: @nimo23 Sonar says that because its analysis engine isn't smart enough to detect that `price` cannot be null there (and it can't). The code isn't wrong, Sonar just isn't smart enough!!! --- As for your suggested fix, again Sonar isn't smart enough to know that calling `compareTo(other.price)` will a null `other.price` value will cause NPE. The code is wrong, Sonar just isn't smart enough!!!

Comment: @nimo23 First, there is no `amount` field here. Second, whether using XOR null check like I suggested or double null check as answer has it, we know that by the time we execute the `if` statement with the `compareTo` call, both will be null or both will be non-null. So with leading `other.price != null &&` check before the `compareTo`, it is ***guaranteed*** that both `price` and `other.price` are not null in the `compareTo` call.

Comment: an alternative would be: `if (price != null ^ other.price != null) return false;
  if (price == null ? other.price != null : price.compareTo(other.price) != 0) return false;` (should be also right, or? ..and this avoids the sonar warnings). However, the code by @MateuszHerych is correct.

Comment: @MateuszHerych I guess you put unneeded complexitiy within your test cases. I put my answer with the optimal code at the bottom of this post..so maybe you can look for..

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an utitly method which can be used to compare two BigDecimals without throwing NPE:

```
// returns true, if val1 is the same as val2
// can this be improved ?
public static boolean isEqual(BigDecimal val1, BigDecimal val2) {
        return !((val1 != null ^ val2 != null) || (val2 != null && val1.compareTo(val2) != 0));
    }
```

This can be used within equals-method:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        final MyProduct other = (MyProduct) obj;

        if(!isEqual(price, other.price)) return false;

        return super.equals(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest way:

```
public static boolean isEqual(BigDecimal val1, BigDecimal val2) {
    return val1 != null ^ val2 != null && val2 != null && val1.compareTo(val2) != 0;
}
```

and then use it within equals():

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        final MyProduct other = (MyProduct) obj;

        if(!isEqual(price, other.price)) return false;

        return super.equals(obj);
    }
```

Comment: I check this with `val1 != null && val2 != null` so if both are null then equals() returns false. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, but `null == null`, so if both are nulls then you should proceed with the flow and just do `super.equals(obj)`. Why `MyProduct(null)` wouldn't be equal to another `MyProduct(null)`?

Comment: Ohhh yes, I did forget this. Thanks. I edited the code to `return val1 != null ^ val2 != null && val2 != null && val1.compareTo(val2) == 0;`. So this should be right, or? Little complex..

Comment: Such things should be build into jdk, something like `BigDecimal.equals()` which checks against nulls and value independent of their scales..

Comment: @MateuszHerych I find your answer is better (simpler)..forget my approach..